# jquery mobile event is not bound when coming back to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am working on a jquery mobile app and have a problem with binding an on-change event to a file input element. The event fires correctly the first time I visit page1.php. But after visiting another jquery site (page2.php) and than comming back to page1.php the event does not fire (as I debugged with inspect-tool of chrome, the event is not even bound the second time I visit page1-php).

I have also tried different page events for binding the event as described in http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile
and http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/

Here is the code of the **page1.php**:

```js
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#serialSelect', function(){           
  $("#qrImageSelect").off('change', '#qrImageFile').on('change','#qrImageFile' , function(){
    var selectedFiles = $('#qrImageFile')[0].files;
    serialNumber = readSerialNumber(selectedFiles);
    window.location.href = "page2.php?sn="+serialNumber;
  });      
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<form id="qrImageSelect" class="ui-btn ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left fileinput-button" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <span>QR code</span>
  <input type="file" name="qrImageFile" data-role="none" id="qrImageFile" />
</form>
```

**page2.php** (same jquery version)

```
<a href="page1.php" data-role="button" class="serial-model-button">
```

Why is the event not bound when coming back to page1?
I would appreciate any help :)

*Edit:*
Some background information: I would like to load a picture of a QR code. The QR code contains a serialNumber. Depending on the serialNumber i want to load a relating page. It should be possible to get back from this site to scan a new QR code. Sombody have an idea to solve that problem in a different way?

Comment: Going back and forth between pages makes new `requests` to the server each time, its like starting from zero, no events have been initialized.

Comment: But it works the first time i load the page (like when i reload page1). But when coming directly back from page2 it doesnt work. If it "starts from zero" it should work in the same manner as when I reload the page?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you for you help so far. I would like to load a picture of a QR code. The QR code contains a serialNumber. Depending on the serialNumber i want to load a  relating page. It should be possible to get back from this site to scan a new QR code. Hope this is understandable...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause of the problem:

When clicking on the link on page2.php, jQuery is actually just getting the contents of the first data-role="page" div and inserting that into the current page (page2.php). This is the default AJAX navigation (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/)

So the script in page1.php (which actually stands in the html-header) is not run at all.

There are two solutions:
If you want to keep the AJAX navigation so you get nice page transitions, then move the script within the data-role="page" DIV.
I prefered the other option: Prevent AJAX navigation by adding data-ajax="false" to your links.

```
<a href="page1.php" data-role="button" class="serial-model-button" data-ajax="false" >
```